# Getting a cell value from an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table structure like this;

```
"<td>",
    "<table class='ead' name=\""+i+"\" id=\""+x+"\" border='0'>",
        "<tr id='e'>",
            "<td class='estimate' name=\""+i+"\" id=\""+x+"\">0</td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr id='a'>",
            "<td class='actual' name=\""+i+"\" id=\""+x+"\">"+keyVal[key]+"</td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr id='d' >",
            "<td class='difference' name=\""+i+"\" id=\""+x+"\">"+day_total+"</td>",
        "</tr>",
    "</table>",
"</td>"
```

You can see the `<td>` tags because it is nested inside another table. In the parent table there are 5 columns but possibly hundreds of rows. There is only 1 column in the child table and only ever 3 rows.

I have a function that allows me to edit the `<td>` row estimate;

```
$(document).on("click", ".estimate", function() {
var myName = parseInt($(this).attr("NAME"));
var myId = parseInt($(this).attr("ID"));

$('.estimate').editable(function(value, settings) { 
    console.log(value);
    return(value);
 },
 {type      : 'textarea',
     //cancel    : 'Cancel',
     event     : 'dblclick',
     //submit    : 'OK',
     indicator : '<img src="images/indicator.gif">',
     tooltip   : 'Double-click this value to edit...',
     width     : '40px',
     height    : '21px',
     onblur    : 'submit'
 });
});
```

This works fine and the new value is posted to the table. The problem is I need to do a calculation with the new value; so I would need to get the value of actual and post the the difference (actual - new estimate) into difference.

I am having trouble getting the unique value of actual. The id=x and name=i are the position of the loop values posting the data into the table.

Any help appreciated!!

Chris

Comment: Please provide the link to download the js file which supports editable plugin? otherwise we couldn't help you

Answer (score 0):

Its ok, a little bit of a structure change got it...instead of a loop value I gave it its own unique index incrementing 1 for each occurrence. Once I had that I could reference each tag by that value.

```
"<td class='estimate' name=\""+IdIndex+"\" id=\"estimate"+IdIndex+"\">0</td>",
```

Then I just did the sums;

```
IDVal = $(this).attr("ID");
NameVal = parseInt($(this).attr("NAME"));
$('.estimate').editable(function(value, settings) { 
    myActual = "#actual"+NameVal;
    myDiff = "#diff"+NameVal;
    $($(myDiff)).text(value - $(myActual).text());
    return(value);
```